# C++ Struct node, how insert string and removing specific node?

Tags: c++

Anyone can help with my code?
im not able to insert string text with space.
other than that..the remove function for removing last node isnt working well..
basically this a doubly linked list, storing 3 element in a node, which is 2 string and 1 integer.it require the user to enter each element and put it into a node.
*how if i need to declare string Cusname inside struct node?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;


void AddToStart();
void RemoveNodeAt();
void createlist();
void PrintList();
void AddToEnd();
void menu();
int option,num;
char name[50], tran[200], delname[50];

struct node
{
    struct node *previous;
    char CusName[50];
    int Customer_Number;
    char Trans[200];
    struct node *next;
}*insertnode,*list,*next,*prev,*temp,*tmpdisplay,*del,*Lnode;


void main()
    {   
createlist();

do 
{
    menu();
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1: AddToStart();break;
    case 2: AddToEnd();break;
    case 3: PrintList();break;
    case 4: RemoveNodeAt();break;
    case 5: exit(1);break;
    }
}while (option !=5);

}

void createlist()
{
    list=NULL;

}

void menu()
{
printf("\n=====================================================\nCustomers' Transactions\n");
printf("1-- Insert at Begining\n");
printf("2-- Insert at End\n");
printf("3-- Print List\n");
printf("4-- Remove a Customer\n");
printf("5-- Quit Programe\n");
printf("Select your option : ");
scanf("%d",&option);
}
void AddToStart()
{
insertnode=(struct node*) malloc (sizeof(struct node));


printf("Insert Customer Name : ");
scanf("%s",&name);
strcpy(insertnode->CusName,name);
printf("Insert Customer Number : ");
scanf("%d",&num);
insertnode->Customer_Number=num;    
printf("Enter Customer Transaction Description : \n");
scanf("%s",&tran);
strcpy(insertnode->Trans,tran);

insertnode->next=NULL;
insertnode->previous=NULL;
if (list==NULL)

    list=insertnode;

else 
    {
        insertnode->next=list;
        list=insertnode;

}
}


void RemoveNodeAt()
{
    printf("Customer to delete : ");
    scanf("%s",delname);

    if (list==NULL)
    printf("\nList is empty \n\n");

    else
    { 

        if (strcmp(delname,list->CusName)==0) //only first node
            //list=NULL;
            printf("DONE");

        else if (strcmp(delname,Lnode->CusName)==0)//last node
            Lnode->previous->next =NULL;

        else

            del=list;
            while (strcmp(del->CusName,delname)!=0)
            {
                prev=del;
                del=del->next;
            }
            {
            prev->next=prev->next->next;
            del->next=del->previous;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with `RemoveNodeAt()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take strings with space as input, you can use `getline`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: printf("Insert Customer Name : ");
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
(insertnode->CusName,name);


i tried this..but end up the output it show some weird symbol.
or mayb i wrote with wrong way?or when i got wrong when insert it into the node?

Comment: thanks..
hmm..any idea?am i locate the node correctly?
i mean this (insertnode->CusName,name);

Answer (score 0):

you can use gets(); function as well to get string with spaces.
can you elaborate more about the problem with removing nodes.

also you can visit   http://basiccodings.blogspot.in/

Comment: my code now function already..now left only one error..which is when removing the first node..it has error...can i like send u my code and you help me check?

Comment: sure. send it at iqbal.muddassir@gmail.com.
make sure to mention your problem